Apply gradle to Kotlin dsl, but android blocks are not recognized
I'm working on converting an existing project to a multi-module structure and setting up the Gradle configuration. In the process, I've moved the plugins' IDs(excluding the application), the Android block, and the dependency block  from the existing Gradle file to a new base-build.gradle.kts file outside the app module.
My current Gradle setup is as follows:
build.gradle.kts (app module)
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
}

apply(from = "../base-build.gradle.kts")

base-build.gradle.kts
apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
apply(plugin = "kotlin-parcelize")
apply(plugin = "com.google.devtools.ksp")
apply(plugin = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android")

android {
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        // ...
    }

    // Dependency implementations
}

The namespace specified the package name in the manifest.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.guri.raffitcompose">

However, when I sync the project, I'm getting the following error:
e: file:///A:/Android%20Project/RaffitCompose/base-build.gradle.kts:11:1: Unresolved reference: android
android { <- in the base-build.gradle.kts file is causing the issue, and I'm not sure why it's not being recognized.
My project-level build.gradle.kts file looks like this:
buildscript {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.9.23"
    val hiltVersion = "2.50"

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.2")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hiltVersion")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.3.2" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.3.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.23" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.23-1.0.20" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.50" apply false
}

// settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven("https://jitpack.io")
    }
}

rootProject.name = "RaffitCompose"
include(":app")
include(":core")

I'm also getting a warning in the repositories block:
Cannot access class 'org.gradle.api.Action'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
I tried adding classpath("org.gradle:gradle-api:8.3.2") to my build script dependencies and it didn't solve the problem.
I tried adding classpath("org.gradle:gradle-api:8.3.2") to my build script dependencies and it didn't solve the problem.
The project works fine using the Groovy DSL, but I'm having trouble using the Kotlin DSL. I'm not sure if I'm missing something in my Gradle configuration.
For the Groovy DSL configuration, I've set it up as follows:
build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

apply from: "../base-build.gradle"

dependencies {
    implementation(project(path: ':features:detail'))
    implementation(project(path: ':features:feed'))
    ...
}

base-build.gradle
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
   ....
}

dependencies {
    // ...implementations
}


The way we separate build config files in Groovy is unfortunately not supported in Kotlin DSL anymore. You can use precompiled script plugin instead. Check this thread discussing the same problem.
Since your build.gradle.kts is almost empty, the easiest workaround is to inline your base-build.gradle.kts to the build.gradle.kts.
